# Why is Celery not shutting down cleanly?

Tags: python, celery

After issuing TERM signal to the Celery worker twice (Warm shutdown and cold shutdown) using Ctlr-C keyboard interrupt, the Celery worker is just hung up. It's not consuming messages or executing tasks (as expected) but it's not shutting down either.

I ran `strace` on the Celery processes to see what's going on behind the scene. Here's the `strace` output on the PID of the Celery main process

```
strace -p 27867
Process 27867 attached - interrupt to quit
futex(0xb966a78, FUTEX_WAIT, 0, NULL
```

And here's what I found doing `strace` on the child processes:

```
strace -p 27874
Process 27874 attached - interrupt to quit
select(4, [3], NULL, NULL, {0, 562000}) = 0 (Timeout)
futex(0x871a808, FUTEX_WAKE, 1)         = 0
select(4, [3], NULL, NULL, {1, 0})      = 0 (Timeout)
futex(0x871a808, FUTEX_WAKE, 1)         = 0
......................................................
```

I know I could issue a KILL signal to the processes to get rid of them. But I'm curious to learn what is actually preventing these processes to be shutdown, and if it's possible to do something about it.

Software stack: Python 2.6.2, Celery 2.4.6, CentOS 5.0

UPDATE: The CPU usage is down to almost 0%. These tasks are quite CPU intensive, so this confirms no tasks are currently active.

Answer (score 5):

From the [docs](http://ask.github.com/celery/userguide/workers.html#worker-stopping):

> If the worker won’t shutdown after considerate time, for example
>   because of tasks stuck in an infinite-loop, you can use the KILL
>   signal to force terminate the worker, but be aware that currently
>   executing tasks will be lost (unless the tasks have the acks_late
>   option set).

Also from [google groups](http://groups.google.com/group/celery-users/browse_thread/thread/545eead6b33159f4/8618c5f5dadd13bf?lnk=gst&q=TERM%20signal#8618c5f5dadd13bf):

> celeryd will not shut down until all active tasks have been processed,
>   where active  means the tasks that have been started on (not all
>   reserved tasks).  The reserved messages will be released and
>   redelivered once the connection channel  is closed.  This happens
>   after the active tasks have returned.  if you don't have a
>   --time-limit enabled celeryd will never kill your tasks at shutdown, even  if they take DAYS to complete.

Comment: there are no active tasks. The tasks that had been running at the time of issuing the stop signal were finished. The queue length remains the same. Nothing is being output to the logs. But the processes are still not terminating.

As I said, I *can* issue a KILL and get rid of them. But this won't be much of an effective solution. To reliably use this software, I need to be able to stop (and start) it automatically w/ little or no manual intervention.

Comment: A good solution for this is to daemonize celery. Supervisord is an excellent candidate.

Comment: I'm using the Generic init scripts for daemonizing the workers: https://github.com/ask/celery/blob/master/contrib/generic-init.d/celeryd